# Is there a way to allow standard users to restart (stop/start) the Print Spooler?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, printer

For some reason, multiple laptops on our wifi network often lose the ability to print to a device attached to a server on the network.  Restarting the Print Spooler on each laptop fixes the issue.  However, restarting the Windows Print Spooler service (via either `services.msc` or via the `net start/stop` command) requires administrative privileges.

Is there a way to allow standard users to restart their local print spooler service without requiring elevation or administrative privileges?  For example, via a policy change?

Comment: try secpol.msc local security policy i beleive they changed the shortcut in Win7/Vista but im sure it would be easyt o find

Comment: The sc command allows you to change the permissions on a service.  I believe the options are sdshow and sdset.  The SDDL syntax is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: `sc sdshow spooler` shows service permissions.  Need to decipher SDDL syntax to make changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up using Method 3 at [How to grant users rights to manage services in Windows 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288129).

1. Download and install [SubInACL.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23510)
2. run `"C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\subinacl" /service Spooler /grant=<username>=TO`

`SubInACL` works on Windows 7.

The `T` grant parameter is for `start service` access and the `O` parameter is `stop service` access.

Now `<username>` can:

- run `sc stop Spooler` and `sc start Spooler`
- run `net stop "Print Spooler"` and `net start "Print Spooler"`
- use the `Restart` button on the `Print Spooler` item in `services.msc`

Comment: Awesome. As an admin, I've been remoting to a user's PC to do this over and over and over and... but no more, thanks to you!

Comment: Whoops... when I tried this (elevated) for the service MySQL I got "MySQL - OpenService Error : 5 Access is denied"

Comment: This does not work. It makes no difference. Standard users still get `System error 5 has occurred` and `Access is denied`. I'm running Windows 10 though.

Comment: I simplified it by granting access to the group "everyone" and it worked great, including on Windows 10.  Note: don't include the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
SetACL: Windows ACL management
http://sourceforge.net/projects/setacl/

SetACL + GUI = SetACL Studio
http://helgeklein.com/setacl-studio/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This answer doesn't explain how the software solved the user's problem. Compare to the other answer. [We have recommendations on our meta site on how to write great software recommendations](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330), please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

[An old blog entry](http://kvz.io/blog/2008/03/26/allow-windows-users-to-restart-service/) has the correct solution (look under "Allow All Authenticated Users to Restart Service"). Run the following once in an elevated command prompt:

```
sc sdset Spooler "D:AR(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA) (A;;LCRPWP;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY) S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)"
```

*Replace `Spooler` with the name of whatever service users need to restart. Use the rest of the line exactly as-is. I don't know what it means, but it works. :-)*

After a few seconds, you will see this response:

```
[SC] SetServiceObjectSecurity SUCCESS
```

Now all authenticated users can restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

First inspect and document existing default permissions.
From an elevated command prompt, type:

```
sc.exe sdshow spooler
```

Results:
D:(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)

Key to reading the output:

> D: — Discretionary ACL (DACL)
> S: — System Access Control List (SACL)

The first letter means; allow (A) or deny (D)

The next set of symbols is assignable permissions:

> CC — SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG (request service settings)
> LC — SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS (service status polling)
> SW — SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS
> LO — SERVICE_INTERROGATE
> CR — SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL
> RC — READ_CONTROL
> RP — SERVICE_START
> WP — SERVICE_STOP
> DT — SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE

The list of trustees is long, but we are looking for Authenticated Users (AU) which is contained in the first set of parenthesis.

Adding RP, WP, and DT permissions for authenticated users (AU) should do the trick:

(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC**RPWPDT**;;;AU)

To set these permissions, again from an elevated command prompt:

```
sc.exe sdset spooler "D:(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRCRPWPDT;;;AU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)"
```

To restore permissions to their defaults, effectively removing the ability of authenticated users to start/stop/pause/resume the spooler service:

```
sc.exe sdset spooler "D:(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)"
```

Much of the credit must be given to IT Connect of University of Washington at https://itconnect.uw.edu/wares/msinf/other-help/understanding-sddl-syntax/